# Visual studio 2017 diagram designer toolbox only have comment in my C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, class-diagram

I want to use VS diagram designer tool but I can't find class or interfaces or other things to add only comments and pointers are shown.
How could I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's seemingly an IDE problem. You can try the following methods step-by-step:

1. Try resetting the `Toolbox` by selecting `Reset Toolbox` after right-clicking on it.

[image: Reset Toolbox]

2. If the above method doesn't works, try resetting IDE preferences to its factory settings (located in `Tools > Import & export settings` of the Top Menu bar):

[image: IDE Reset Method]